# Can appium be run on windows to test iOS app?

Tags: appium

Can I use Appium to test iOS app on Windows 7?
Actually I have planned to test an iOS app, but i do not have the mac machine, will I need xcode to use appium for iOS app?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can not do that, please refer to this link: [You can not test iOS app on Windows](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-appium-on-windows)

**LIMITATIONS
If you are running Appium on Windows, you can use the Appium.exe client, which will allow you to quickly launch an Appium server and use the Inspector. You will not be able to test iOS apps on a locally hosted server, because Appium relies on OS X-only libraries to support iOS testing. You can however use the Remote Server option to connect to an Appium server running on a Mac.**

Having said this, if you can install Mac OS within your Windows OS in virtual environment, then you will be able to do it.

Comment: Im really in to perform some iOS testing on a virtual environment using appium,There for could you lease give some more details on "using remote server" option

Comment: @ChathuD, do you have a Mac running Appium available atm?

Comment: Yes boss,Im having a mac.But the thing is already i have a test suite which i create using c# in order to run tests on android.So i just need to use the smae c# code to run the test on iOS device,

Comment: Which emulator have you use for testing iOs app.

Comment: @DeepakN, only the emulator that comes with Xcode

Answer (score 1):

One of the major obstacles with testing iOS apps is the need for iOS devices or Xcode to run the app on a Simulator.
Apple doesn’t support running Xcode on any other operating system or hardware rather than macOS on Macs.
When it comes to Appium tests, Xcode is also required to build, sign, provision and run a special project that operates as a driver, executing the automation.

However, with the test automation platform called TestProject, which enhances Appium’s driver, you can easily run iOS tests on a Windows operating system without the need for macOS. There’s a really nice tutorial on that here: [Setup iOS Test Automation on Windows using TestProject | TestProject](https://blog.testproject.io/2019/01/29/setup-ios-test-automation-windows-without-mac/)